# Replace matching word with a digit/number in a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to replace some words in a string with a digit/number only if that word is followed or preceded by a digit [whitespace(s) allowed in between]. For example, here is an example string in which I wish to replace **too** with 2 and **for** with 4. I have tried with str_replace, but doesn't serve the full purpose as it replaces all **for** and **too** in the string

```
$str = 'Please wait for sometime too, the area code is for 18 and phone number is too 5897 for';
$str = str_ireplace(' for ', '4', $str);
$str = str_ireplace(' too ', '2', $str);
echo $str;
```

but it isn't giving me the desired output which should be
**Please wait for sometime too, the area code is 418 and phone number is 258974**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a little too long, but you get the idea:

http://3v4l.org/JfXBN

```
<?php
$str="Please wait for sometime too, the area code is for 18 and phone number is too 5897 for";
$str=preg_replace('#(\d)\s*for#','${1}4',$str);
$str=preg_replace('#(\d)\s*too#','${1}2',$str);
$str=preg_replace('#for\s*(\d)#','4${1}',$str);
$str=preg_replace('#too\s*(\d)#','2${1}',$str);
echo $str;
```

Outputs:

> Please wait for sometime too, the area code is 418 and phone number is 258974

#### Warning:

If your string looks like this: `8 too for`,
this code snippet may or may not fail depending on whether you expect `824` or `82 for`, since it does not do recursive replace (the current sequence returns `82 for`).

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~\d\K\h*(?:too|for)|(?:too|for)\h*(?=\d)~i', 
     function($m) {
        return strtr(strtolower(trim($m[0])), array('too'=>2,'for'=>4));
     }, $str);
```